# How to add users from one tenant to another tenant without outlook access to accept invitation?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant configuration set up in Azure. In my main tenant, there is a security policy in place that restricts the access to the portal to only users that don't have an E1 license and therefore do not have access to Outlook.
I am looking to configure multi-tenancy so that I don’t have to manage two separate tenants. However, I am encountering an issue when trying to add users from my main tenant to my second tenant. The standard process requires users to accept an invitation via Outlook, which is not possible for my users as they do not have Outlook access.
Is there a workaround or alternative method that would allow me to add users from my main tenant to my second tenant without requiring Outlook access to accept the invitation?

I was expecting to have some sort of accepting the invite without requiring the user to access outlook to accept the invitation.

Answer (score 1):

I just today created my account so sorry if my answer doesn't come through as the most readable, but I think what you are looking for is to use the Cross-Tenant sync.

The Cross-Tenant sync allows you to create users from one tenant into another as B2B users without generating an invitation.

You can check additional details on Microsoft's learn page [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/multi-tenant-organizations/cross-tenant-synchronization-overview).